# How to remove duplicate tuples after join?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm struggling with a simple SQL query.
There are two relations: movieGenre(movieID, genreName), movie(movieID, movieName).
I need to make a new table of movieNames that share a common genre.
This is the query I came up with :

```
with movie_info(movieid, genreName, movieName) as (
    select
        movieID,
        genreName,
        movieName
    from
        movieGenre natural
        join movie
)
select
    m2.genreName,
    m1.movieName,
    m2.movieName
from
    movie_info as m1,
    movie_info as m2
where
    m1.movieID <> m2.movieID
    and m1.genreName = m2.genreName
order by
    m1.genreName,
    m1.movieName;
```

And the result looks like this :
[image: result]

But as you can see, tuple #1 and #2 represent the same thing(just like #3 and #6, #9 and #10) so I want only one of them to be shown.

Is there a way I could fix this?

Comment: You should always disclose actual table definitions showing data types and constraints (`CREATE TABLE` statements) and your version of Postgres. As well as the objective of the query. Chances are, this can be more efficient. Also, the relational design  you disclosed doesn't seem to make sense, possibly due to over-simplification in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change unequal condition to > and it handle duplicates :

also instead of implicit join "," use implicit join

```
with movie_info(movieid, genreName, movieName) as (
    select
        movieID,genreName,movieName
    from movieGenre 
    natural join movie
)
select
    m2.genreName,
    m1.movieName,
    m2.movieName
from
    movie_info as m1
join movie_info as m2
  on m1.genreName = m2.genreName
where
    m1.movieID < m2.movieID -- < here
order by
    m1.genreName,m1.movieName;
```

Comment: I'm new to SQL and this worked properly. Thanks a lot.